# sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() is always empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, model-view-controller

I'm trying to expire the sessions of my users when I update / delete them. This is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry () {

    return new SessionRegistryImpl();

}
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() { //(5)
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}

@Override
protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("*.jsp").authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?failed=1")
            .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")               
        .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout.html")
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    http.sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(100)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
        .expiredUrl("/ejercicios-programacion/")
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

}
```

But when I do:

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

private boolean isEmpty () {

    return sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().isEmpty();

}
```

(Obviously my class is a @Component so it is initialized by Spring)

It returns true, even though I'm logged in with 3 different users in different browser windows. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try @Service instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already fixed this particular problem by joining the http.sessionmanagement with the other http request, now I have another problem, which I'm waiting for the 90 min wait time to go away to post, but basically when I expire all the sessions of a user, and I reload a page (logged with the user I expired), I get a nullpointerexception

Comment: Are you using expireNow()? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#session-mgmt use this approach as well it is on Github https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-track-logged-in-users

Comment: Yeep, I'm using expireNow

Comment: @DavidAntelo I have the same problem (as in your roiginal post) but i do not understand how you fixed this - what do you mean by 'joining the http.sessionmanagement with the other http request' ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Please provide solution in the answer.

Comment: If you're using custom authentication then it will not work out of the box and have to make some configurations. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65542389/9004116